# Scala - filter out null values in a Array[Map[String,Int]]

Tags: scala

I have an Array of [Map[String,Int] like this:

```
val orArray = Array(Map("x" -> 24, "y" -> 25, "z" -> 26), null, Map("x" -> 11, "y" -> 22, "z" -> 33), null, Map("x" -> 111, "y" -> 222, "z" -> 333))
```

I want to remove the null elements in this array, to get something like:

```
Array[Map[String,Int]] = (Map("x" -> 24, "y" -> 25, "z" -> 26),  Map("x" -> 11, "y" -> 22, "z" -> 33),  Map("x" -> 111, "y" -> 222, "z" -> 333))
```

I was trying this so far

```
orArray.filterNot(p => p.isEmpty)
```

But it generates a NullPointerException. How could I filter out those two null values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply check the `null` values as

```
orArray.filter(map  => map != null)
```

Output:

```
Map(x -> 24, y -> 25, z -> 26), Map(x -> 11, y -> 22, z -> 33), Map(x -> 111, y -> 222, z -> 333)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Short hand notation for filter:  .filter(_ != null)